# C# Regex delete '[]'

Tags: c#, regex

I've got this simple code:

```
Regex remove2 = new Regex("[(\"{}\r)]");
str = remove2.Replace(str, "");
```

I need to delete: `[` and `]` chars, how do that?

When I simply added `[]` between `""` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the [ and ] characters - try

```
Regex remove2 = new Regex("\[(.*)\]");
str = remove2.Replace(str, "$1");
```

By wrapping part of the pattern inside parentheses you are in effect saving it for later usage. It can be accessed via the construct $1 in the replacement command. If you had a second  string captured inside parentheses it would be access via $2, etc.

Comment: Now i have error: Unrecognized escape sequence after \     i tried with double \ but still not worked.

Answer (score 0):

No regex but does also remove brackets:

```
str = new string(str.Where(c => !"[]".Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding brackets — specifically a `]` — to the set matched in the RE, you've got to be careful about where you put it; it must be the *first* character in the set (which works because you're not allowed to make an empty set). So…

```
Regex remove2 = new Regex("[][(\"{}\r)]")
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple code will remove square brackets:

```
     string str1 = "test=[[]]][[]";
     string res = Regex.Replace(str1, "[][]","");
```